# How to Terraform Plan multiple AWS accounts and then review and then apply to multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Currently we have about 30 AWS accounts (and growing)  and we have a script that goes through and plans them all one by one and then we look at the plan and then we apply it if it looks correct.  Then it goes on to the next account.  I am wondering if there is a way to get the plan for all accounts and then if they all look good to kick off the apply for all accounts at once so we don't have to do it one by one each time.

Comment: Absolutely don't do this. You will make mistakes and cause big issues. If you wanted to do this then your best bet would be to keep all accounts in the same directory and single `apply` them which would give you the same result but is strongly discouraged for the amount of blast radius on this. Think about how you want to automate things and what you're comfortable with but I'd definitely not apply out changes to multiple accounts at the same time ever.

Comment: If you really did want to do this then [`terragrunt` provides the ability to do this](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt#the-apply-all-destroy-all-output-all-and-plan-all-commands) for you but I'd still say it's a bad idea.